# Изменить значение, но не отсылать сигнал об изменении

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, сигналы-слоты

Возможно ли изменить значение `QSlider` но при этом сделать так, что бы сигнал об изменении не был отправлен в определенном случае?

Такая возможность необходима для того что бы избежать зацикливания установки, и отображения информации о позиции на `QSlider`. Если такого не сделать выходит следующая ситуация:

1. Получили сигнал об изменении значения
2. Установили значение для `QSlider`
3. Связанный объект получил сигнал об изменении значения `QSlider` и отправил его обратно
4. Вернулись к 1му пункту и по новой

Вот такую ситуацию пытаюсь избежать, но пока ничего не вышло, но подумалось о том что возможно можно сделать так, что бы сигнал в определенных ситуациях не отправлялся?

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться методом [QObject::blockSignals(bool)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals):

```
// Получили сигнал об изменении значения 
void SomeClass::someValueChanged(int value) {
    // Заблокировать сигнал из слайдера
    slider->blockSignals(true);
    // Установили значение для QSlider. Никакие сигналы отправляться не будут
    slider->...
    // Разблокировать сигнал из слайдера
    slider->blockSignals(false);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверяйте явно, изменилось ли значение и только в том случае, если изменилось, посылайте сигнал. Это обычная практика. Выглядит это как-то так:

```
void setValue(const T& value)
{
    if(value == m_Value)
        return;
    m_Value = value;
    emit valueChanged(value);
}
```